# Regex letters can't repeat

Tags: regex

Need regex for 0|1, except the letters can't repeat.

So:

```
101010 - valid
010101 - valid
110011 - invalid
```

Comment: People voted down because you asked for an answer without showing that you had attempted the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1?(01)*0? // matches alternating 1s and 0s
^1?(01)*0?$ // same as above but only whole strings
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is pretty trivial:

```
(?=[01])0?(?:10)*1?
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that trivial...

Comment: Why do you include the Followed-By directive?  It seems to perform the same with and without it.

Comment: @CaffGeek: I didn't have the look-ahead when I wrote that. It's probably not so trivial with that.

Comment: @Wug: Because `0?(?:10)*1?` can legally match an empty string. I use the `(?=[01])` to make sure we're getting at least one character (i.e. at least one `0` or `1`).